# Subscript out of range for some users

Tags: vba, excel

I have written the below sub in Excel 2010 VBA that takes a value from one worksheet, opens a new workbook and copies it in. This code works perfectly for me. I have another person trying to run this code. They happen to be using Excel 2007 and get a Subscript out of range error on the following line: Not sure what to do with this.

```
Workbooks("Log_File").Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & First_Blank_Row) =    Value1
```

Code:

```
Sub Open_Results()
Range("B14") = "=sum(A10:A20)"

Value1 = Range("B14").Value

'open the log file
Application.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Log\Log_File.xlsx")


First_Blank_Row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'**ERROR STARTS AT THIS NEXT LINE**
Workbooks("Log_File").Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & First_Blank_Row) =    Value1

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Most likely -- the Worksheet "Data" does not exist in that users workbook.  Check to see if there are non-printing characters before or after the worksheet name on the tab.  Or perhaps test the worksheet name to is if it really is "Data"

Comment: Could this be caused by the new row limits of excel 2010?

Comment: Hi Ron, I just ran a test. The sheet is called "Data". The thing is, it works for me (Excel 2010), but not for a co-worker (Excel 2007). The co-worker is able to open the file, but no write anything to it.

Comment: @Bigtree The code I am using is only about 30 rows of data. Could this be something internal about the row limits that I am not seeing?

Comment: You might check cells().end() in 2007. I remember this didn't work for me in 2003. Basiclly, what is the value of first_blank_row at the time of error?

Comment: @Bigtree Good thought. Just ran the check and First_Blank_Row is 29.

Comment: I would try fully qualifying all ranges, i.e., specifying which worksheet they're in.

Comment: Doug's got a good point. You can also use the watcher to narrow down what part of that line is erroneous.

Comment: I just found a solution to this!

Excel 2007 requires the file extension in the file name whereas Excel 2010 does not. 

    Workbooks("Log_File.xlsx").Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & First_Blank_Row).Value = Value1

Comment: @Bigtree  What new row limits in 2010?  In 2007, the rows were increased to a bit > 10^6.  Was there another change in 2010?

Comment: @user2242044  Using the "C:\Log\Log_File.xlsx" file from the user with 2007 machine, open that file, type <alt-F11>; then, in the immediate window of the VBE, enter ?thisworkbook.Worksheets("Data").name <enter>.  This should return "Data".  If this returns a subscript out of range error, then what looks like "Data" is not.  If it returns "Data", then I'd need to see that particular workbook to try to figure out the problem.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld My bad. I thought the change was made in 2010.

Comment: @Bigtree I'm still using 2007, so am not intimately familiar with 2010.  One of these days, I might get a newer version, but I haven't seen a convincing reason yet.  Although the newest versions do have some better functions for handling arrays of cells.

Comment: @user2242044, what you discovered is a difference in your two Windows settings, i.e., whether you show file extensions in Windows Explorer. That setting will have the same effect in all Excel versions going back to at least 97. If you don't show file extensions in Windows Explorer, your code won't error. If you do, it will.

Comment: For a more thorough explanation, you can't beat Chip Pearson: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/fileextensions.aspx